# Reshaping the 'y' data for LSTM recurrent neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I’m just now learning about recurrent neural NN via LSTM. 
I know that the `X` data needs to be reshaped into 3 dimensional shape when using LSTM for use in a recurrent NN. My issue is with the `y` data.  
For One to One sequence problems and Many to One sequence problems, the `y` data seems to be left as 1 dimensional which makes sense to me. 
But I saw several examples of One to Many sequence problems where the `y` data was left as 1 dimensional instead of being reshaped to 2 dimesional via `y.reshape(-1,1)`.    
This is a bit confusing to me given that for a One to Many sequence problem,  the `y` data has multiple time steps.   
Is there a general rule for when the `y` data needs to be reshaped?

Comment: please provide a concrete example

Comment: I don't really have a concrete example. I'm just trying to get some clarifying guidance as to when the y data has to be reshaped

Comment: _But I saw several examples_ seem pretty concrete examples